# search string in HashMap combine ArrayList on android

Tags: java, android

I am trying **listItem.indexOf(word.text)==-1** to find the string I want.

Using indexOf function in single ArrayList is working fine. but after I use HashMap combine ArrayList, the indexOf function seems not working.

Any solution? thx!

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listItem= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>(); 
SimpleAdapter mSimpleAdapter  = new SimpleAdapter(this,listItem, R.layout.item_main, new String[] {"ItemImage","ItemTitle", "ItemText"},   
                new int[] {R.id.ItemImage,R.id.ItemTitle,R.id.ItemText});

if(listItem.indexOf(word.text)==-1){
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
    map.put("ItemImage", R.drawable.speak2);
    map.put("ItemTitle", word.text);  
    map.put("ItemText", temp);  
    listItem.add(map); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `word.text` is a String. Therefore you have no reason to expect that `listItem.indexOf(word.text)` would find it in a `List` that contains `HashMap` instances.

It looks like you are storing `word.text` as one of the values of a HashMap stored in the list. To search for a HashMap in the List that contains this value you have to iterate over all the Maps in the List, and for each Map, iterate over all its values.

Perhaps a better data structure would be `HashMap<String,HashMap<String, Object>`, where the key is taken from `word.text` and the value is the HashMap you currently store in the list. This way, you could replace `listItem.indexOf(word.text)` with `mapItem.containsKey(word.text)`, which is more efficient, and would work.

```
   HashMap<String,HashMap<String, Object>> mapItem= new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>>(); 

   if(!mapItem.containsKey(word.text)){
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
        map.put("ItemImage", R.drawable.speak2);
        map.put("ItemTitle", word.text);  
        map.put("ItemText", temp);  
        mapItem.put(word.text, map); 
    }
```

Comment: yes.It's a string. Is there any function I could find a string in a List  contains HashMap instances?

Comment: How do I add object as **map.put("ItemText", temp);**
if I use **HashMap<String,HashMap<String, Object>**

Comment: @周瑋傑 I'm not sure I understood your question in this comment, but I edited my answer with an example of how the code would look like if you use a map instead of a list.